# Japanese text garbled while passing to a http restlet service

Tags: http, encoding, utf-8, request

I have a Perl client which is calling an http restlet service (put method). Some of the parameters in this call contain japanese text. When I printed the contents of these request parameters in the restlet service I found these chars garbled !

This is my PERL client code:

```
my %request_headers = (
        'DocumentName' => $document_name, --> This name is a JAPANESE String
        'DocumentDescription' => 'Test Japanese Chars',
        'content-length' => 200,
        'Content-Type' => 'application/octet-stream; charset=utf-8',
        'User-Agent' => "JPCharTester",
        );

        $s->write_request('PUT', '/test-document/TEST/TEST_DOCUMENT' , %request_headers, $content);
```

in this call both the values of $context and $document_name are JAPANESE Strings. But ONLY the document_name is received as garbled in my backend service.

Here goes the Service code:

```
String URL_ENCODING = "UTF-8";
String documentName = requestHeaders.getFirstValue("DocumentName");
System.out.println("Encoded Document Name : "+documentName+" <<<"); --> documentName is garbled here

try {
    documentName = URLDecoder.decode(documentName, URL_ENCODING);
    System.out.println(>>> Decoded Document Name : "+documentName+" <<<"); --> documentName is garbled here
} catch (java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
    throwException(ex.getMessage(), Status.SERVER_ERROR_INTERNAL, ex);
}
```

both the above log statements printed **GARBLED TEXT** !!

Can someone tell me what is the mistake I am doing and how to fix this ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Regards,
Satish.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is character encoding and why should I bother with it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10611455/what-is-character-encoding-and-why-should-i-bother-with-it)

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to *encode* the data on the client side as `UTF-8`. If you say

```
'Content-Type' => 'application/octet-stream; charset=utf-8'
```

than that doesn't magically solve the problem. It's just a hint for the receiver in which form it will get the data. You must also *send* it with the correct format. In perl:

```
use utf8;
...
    'DocumentName' => utf8::encode($document_name),
...

... , utf8::encode($content) ...
```